# magento 2 : How to add static block in (.html) file?

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block, onestepcheckout

I want to add static block over the **Place order**  button! So I have used Firecheckout extension and I found place order button here `view/frontend/web/template/place-order.html` on my extension.

So how can add a static block in this file?

If another way to add static block then also let me know.

Comment: conceptually you should be placing the static block in it's own block using the xml layout files. Is there a reason you need to place this in the .html template? As in, you need the block to sit between other elements in the .html file?

Answer (score 9):

To add static block over the Place order button!, you need to declare a PHTML file in checkout index anywhere in theme.
STEP 1:
Create a new XML file in theme

> checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="static_block" template="Magento_Theme::block/summary.phtml" cacheable="false" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

STEP 2 : create a PHTML file in below location

> app/design/frontend/{theme_package}/{theme_name}/Magento_Theme/templates/block/summary.phtml

```
<?php
    $summaryBlockDetail = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('new-block')->toHtml() ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.summaryBlockDetail = "<?= json_encode($summaryBlockDetail)?>";
</script>
```

STEP 3 :
Add below code in .html file else any where in .html in checkout

> view/frontend/web/template/place-order.html

```
<div class="component-wrapper">
<div class="control">
    <span data-bind="html: summaryBlockDetail"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfect man, but i got static block value with html tag like<p>....</p> , i want only value without tag.

Comment: Yes, I get the solution, check updated answer.

Comment: One More Question, when i add multiple html like <p>...</p><b></b> etc. so it's not show on frontside. Why?

Comment: A few things with step 2. The $summaryBlockDetail line needs to have <?php ?> wrapped around it. You also need to put the block HTML in the addslashes() native php function so it doesn't output quotes and break the javascript variable definition.

Comment: Yes, You can validate your content in summary.phtml file itself in the php tag <?php ...?>

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: If you use this solution, you may want to consider this 2 thing:
1.  disable WYSIWYG Options, because it will show <p></p> surround the cms block and hard for you to call it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175119/8962929
2. use trim($summaryBlockDetail),  it will remove all space which will cause you an error when you call.

Answer (score 0):

html alone can't use php commands, altough, in a mobile project we used jQuery to move static blocks from one part of the page to another onLoad. You'll need to render your static block on another .phtml file that is loaded on the same page and then use jQuery append to move it where you want it to display.

```
jQuery('#destinationContainerId').append(jQuery('#staticBlockId'));
```